# tensorflow gradient return none for custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow

I implement a model with a custom training loop and custom loss function. Loss function return a float value. But while calculate gradient tf.gradient(loss,model.trainable_weights), It gives None gradient.  I know the issue is way of calculate loss. I tried with custom mse loss. It works fine. I want to implement loss function like count_predition_0's+count_predition_1's/label_0's+label_1's. It's a binary classification problem. I set batch size is 100. So model return 100 batch output. I only consider few batch eg out of 100 batch i only consider or filter it out 40 based on input. Both label and prediction in same shape that is not issue here. That label and prediction pass to custom_loss function.

[Notebook link](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/joshuajennysibbu/822ddee4d0f587e475c3927ac8df9c55/untitled29.ipynb)

Comment: Your loss is not differentiable.

Comment: ok.. What it mean? how to solve this issue? This Formula i have to implement  count_predition_0's+count_predition_1's/label_0's+label_1's.

Comment: You cannot use that as a loss, because it is not differentiable, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: differentiable loss means what? Can you send any link?

Comment: You can not minimize the loss using gradient descent if it is not differentiable.